# Passing Parameter over URL

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a `Html.ActionLink` which provides a link including a Parameter (`id = item.ID`):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "../Home/Edit/", new { id = item.ID })
```

When it is clicked it provides following link:

> localhost/Home/Edit/51467

But in my Edit ActionResult the `_id` is null:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int _id)
    {
        DeploymentRequest dr = dbhandler.GetDeploymentReleaseById(_id);
        return View(dr);
    }
```

Why? it should be _id = 51467.

Comment: Change `_id` to `id` in Edit action.

Comment: @ps4 Thanks, it works, I would never have thought of this, must have problems with the '_'. If u want post your comment as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `id` instead of `_id` in action paramater. Both should be the same.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    DeploymentRequest dr = dbhandler.GetDeploymentReleaseById(id);
    return View(dr);
}
```